# python sqlalchemy orm one to many bidirectional relation - mapping a json to multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy orm to map a json to multiple tables.
I have two tables, each for which I have a class.

One of the tables, has a parameter, which is a list of dictionaries and this has to be mapped to different columns of the second table.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(primary_key, Interger(10))
    param1 = Column(String(45))
    param2 = Column(String(45))
    atobmap = relationship('B', lazy='subquery', back_populates="a")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    bid = Column(primary_key=True, nullable=True, Integer(15))
    bparam1 = Column(ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False)
    bparam2 = Column(String(45))
    a = relationship('A', back_populates='b')
```

**sample json:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "param1": "Value",
    "param2": "Value",
    "atobmap": [
                 { "bid": 1,
                   "bparam1": 1,
                   "bparam2": "Value"
                 },
                 { "bid": 2,
                   "bparam1": 1,
                   "bparam2": "Value"
                 }
               ]
}
```

When I manually insert data into the tables and do a GET, its working fine and is returning values as expected, although it adds an _sa_instance_state key with value {} inside my atobmap dictionaries.

```
{
...
"atobmap": [
                 { "_sa_instance_state": {}
                   "bid": 1,
                   "bparam1": 1,
                   "bparam2": "Value"
                 },
                 { "_sa_instance_state": {}
                   "bid": 2,
                   "bparam1": 1,
                   "bparam2": "Value"
                 }
       ]
}
```

But when I try to POST the values, it throws an **error** saying `"Unhashable type: dict".`

Comment: You should add some more code which actually does the insert or what line throws the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function similar to the one below.

It takes an SQLAlchemy model and a dictionary of field/value pairs and
returns a model instance. Ignores keys that are in the dictionary
that aren't fields on the model. Traverses and instantiates relationships.

Example:

Our models include a Company model with a name field that is a string
and a users field that is a one-to-many relation to a User model.

Our data looks like the following.

{
"company":
{
"name": "Owoga"
"users": [
{
"name": "Eric"
}
]
}
}

We will use SQLAlchemy's `class_mapper` function to get the "mapper"
for the model. We can then access `mapper.attrs.keys()` to get a list
of all the mapped fields. Any of those keys that are not relationships, simply
grab them out of the data. For keys that are relationships, get the mapper
of the relationship and then recursively call `from_json` with that related mapper
and the sub-data. Then, attach that new instance[s] to the parent instance.

```
def from_json(model, data):
    mapper = class_mapper(model)
    keys = mapper.attrs.keys()
    relationships = inspect(mapper).relationships
    args = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if k in keys and k not in relationships}
    instance = model(**args)
    for attr, relationship in relationships.items():
        if relationship.direction in [MANYTOMANY, ONETOMANY]:
            relationship_instances = [
                from_json(relationship.mapper.class_, el) for el in data[attr]
            ]
            setattr(instance, attr, relationship_instances)
        elif relationship.direction == MANYTOONE:
            try:
                relationship_instance = from_json(
                    relationship.mapper.class_, data[attr]
                )
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, relationship_instance)
    return instance
```